# DataTemplateSelector in SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, datatemplateselector

I have a set of groups of different types of item, all inheriting form a common base type (ItemBase).  Each of my groups has an Items collection of type `ObservableCollection<ItemBase>`.

In my SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView, I can set a DataTemplateSelector, and in SelectTemplateCore() I can cast the item parameter to detrmine which template to apply.

In my zoomed out view, though, the objects are passed around as DependencyObjects, and I can't for the life of me figure out how I can take the data passsed in to determine which template to use.

To set the items source of the GridView in the zoomed out view, I use

```
(semZm.ZoomedOutView as ListViewBase).ItemsSource = this.groupedItemsViewSource.View.CollectionGroups;
```

as this appears to be the only way to get the zoomedin and zoomedout views to synchronise (when you click on a group in the zoomed out view it should take me to the appropriate place in the zoomedinview to see that group's detail.

So, am I missing something obvious in terms of getting the actual group in SelectTemplateCore(), or failing that is there a better way of binding my ItemsSource of the ZoomedOutView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the appropriate way to handle casting of the DependencyObject to a usable type, see the answer to [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493652/semanticzoom-zoomedoutview-selecteditems-returns-dependencyobject)

Essentially, cast it to [ICollectionViewGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionviewgroup.aspx) to access the members.