# SemanticZoom ZoomedOutView SelectedItems Returns DependencyObject

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In the SemanticZoom control I use the same `CollectionViewSource` for both the zoomed in and zoomed out view. To do this I bind the zoomed out `GridView` in the code behind like this:

```
(FavoriteGroupsSemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView as ListViewBase).ItemsSource = this.FavoriteGroupsViewSource.View.CollectionGroups;
```

Everything works as expected. However, now the zoomed out GridView is bound to a list of DependencyObjects instead of my original groups. And thus when I access the SelectedItems I get a WinRT object that contains a list of DependencyObjects instead of my groups.

How can I access the selected groups of the zoomed out GridView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cast the Dependency Object to an [ICollectionViewGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionviewgroup.aspx) which has the properties *Group* and *GroupItems*.

Comment: And for further issues of the same nature. How would I figure out which interfaces the DependencyObject can be casted to?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no nice way, finding this out took some reading of the MSDN documentation, I noticed this interface was in the same namespace as CollectionViewSource and that it's properties matched what you needed for the binding (the Group property).